# Distributed updating of object collections

Tags: c#, list, design-patterns, class-design

My objects structure in a current program is organized so that a `Doc` object contains a list of `Mention` objects, and each `Mention` object contains a list of `Word` objects. Words are identified by their position in the Doc's text and also store some other information (its text, its wordnet sense...)

In the processing of the program (through user interaction, etc..) `Word` objects inside a `Mention` can be accessed and modified value (for example, update its sense). User interaction with each `Mention` is a requirement.

The problem I met here is that several `Mention`s that belong to the same `Doc` might share some same `Word`s (after all, all words are in the Doc). So when such a Word is updated, how should I update the corresponding `Word` contained in other `Mention`s ? In other words, these `Word`s are in the same exact location in the text and should be updated together, but they are stored separately in Mentions. So how should one update change the others ?

One approach I used is when a `Word` inside a `Mention` is modified, I retrieve all mentions (from a stored `Doc` reference) and then update the corresponding `Word` in any `Mention` that contains it. This requires a for loop with Equals checks on each update, which is quite a lot processing.

The second approach I think of is not to store separate `Word` lists in `Mention`s. Only a single list of `Word`s is store in `Doc`, and in each `Mention` the indices of which `Word`s belong to the `Mention` is store in a list. So when updating a `Word`, I will call an update function from the `Doc`'s reference to update the `Doc`'s list. However, the problem lies in the function that returns the whole list of `Word`s for a `Mention`. I have to return a new list of `Word`s, using the indices I have to pick actual `Word`s inside the `Doc`'s list. This is needed because all `Word`s inside that `Mention` may have been modified by some other `Mention`(s) just shortly before. Alternatively, I can check if a `Word` is updated and copy the update. But it still requires a for loop through all `Word`s in the `Mention`, so it still seems weird (Each time retrieving the list = long operation)

What I want to ask is if there is any better solution to this update problem. Any help is much appreciated :)
If it is necessary, I will add part of my code here.

Comment: Why do you have multiple instances of a `Word` object for the same physical word in the text? You should only have one that is shared among all `Mention` instances that need to use it.

Comment: Yeah, what you refer to is implemented in my second approach. It sill has the problem when I want to retrieve a "possibly" updated version of words list for a mention.

Comment: No, it is not the same. My point is that each `Mention` has a list of `Word`s - and not their indices - and can simply update that `Word` instance. Since other `Mention`s that contain the same word have the exact same `Word` instance, they will always automatically operate on the latest version. No manual updating is required.

Comment: How is that possible ? It seems you are misunderstanding something here. 

For example: firstly Word w1 = (2,3,"age",1), w2 = (2,3,"age",1) are supposedly the same word in the Doc.

Then when you update w1 : w1 = (2,3,"age",3)

Then how can w2 is updated ? It belongs to another list, in another Mention object, and its fourth member is still 1.

The problem here is that each Mention store a list of words separately. Initially they are the same, but what if they are changed ?

Comment: Do you want the fourth member of `w2` to stay 1, even after the update? Or should it be updated to 3?

Comment: Of course I want it to update to 3.
That's the whole point of my two attempts mentioned in my first post :) I think it can't be automatically done. Something similar to Object o1 = o2 = someObject; Then we change o1 and o2 is not affected. But then again, when applying to lists, things might take too much time so I feel it is a bit awkward and there should be some other ways to optimize ?

Comment: Please see my answer. As I said, simply share the `Word` instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already said in my comments, don't create multiple `Word` instances for the same word in the document. So, regarding your comment: There never would be a `w1` and `w2` for a single physical word in the document. There only would be `w`.

Example:

```
var w = new Word(2, 3, "age", 1)

var mention1 = new Mention(w);
var mention2 = new Mention(w);

mention1.UpdateWord(); // sets the fourth property of w to 3

mention2.PrintWord(); // prints (2, 3, "age", 3)
```

This works, because both `Mention` instances work on the *same* `Word` instance.

Comment: But the problem is I receive my input from another program. In particular, the Mention and their according words are stored in a text file: 
Mention1
w1_2_3_"age" w2_8_5_after"...
sth like that. I have to parse these text to create the Mentions. So after your answer I think I have to have an intial phase of find all words first. Only then could I create each Mention using the specific words for each Mention.

I think I really got a bit confused earlier :(

Comment: @ramcrys You can use a dictionary to store the `Word` instance for a word from that and use that stored instance at the next occurrence of the same word in the file. If you don't understand that, please paste such a file at http://pastebin.com so I can show you some code that actually works for your case.

Comment: Sorry, I was really confused when doing it earlier. Now that it is pointed out by you, I can fix it. Thanks for your help a lot.

Comment: @ramcrys: Nice. Good luck doing that :-)